# Exporting an Excel sheet to a .csv file having options to select path and filename using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I save or export an Excel sheet to a csv file?

Sheet 1 is where the convert button located.
[image]

Sheet 2 contains the records I want save or export.

I want to select location and file name for that file. Something like this
[image]

```vb
Sub FileSaveExcel()
    Dim s As Worksheet

    For Each s In Sheets
        If s.Name = "Template" Then

            Dim wb As Workbook, InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String

            InitFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

            Sheets("Template").Copy

            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitFileName, _
              filefilter:="Excel files , *.csv")

            With wb
                If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
                    .SaveAs fileSaveName
                    .Close
                Else
                    .Close False
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

The file was was successfully exported.

Upon opening it, it prompted me this message:

> The file and extension of "filename.csv" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you it anyway?

I choose yes. I notice the formats are set in .xlsm but the file extension was already in .csv.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Where did you get stuck or errors? Checkout the [Worksheet.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas). Note that your `.SaveAs` refers to the workbook not the worksheet!

Comment: The file was was successfully exported but after upon opening it, it prompted me this message: 

The file and extension of "filename.csv" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you it anyway?

I choose yes. i notice the formats are set in .xlsm but the file extension was already in .csv.

Comment: Please read the the link I gave in my first comment you need to set the right fileformat.